# Pointer that can point to multiple classes

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm developing a game. There's a "Player" class and an "NPC" class.

Each instance of these classes can have a "target". That target can be another player or another NPC. I'd like this "target" value to point to the instance of the Player/NPC that the Player/NPC has selected.

So the problem being, with my current setup I've got 2 pointers for each Player/NPC in the form of:

```
Player* target_p;
NPC* target_n;
```

This obviously isn't optimal. What I'm asking is if there is a way to make a pointer which can point to either of these classes, and not just one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Canb you derive these classes from a common base class?

Comment: Thanks for the very fast and useful responses. I've implemented a base class now and all works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make common base class for `Player` and `NPC`. This base class can have common field from `Player` and `NPC` or just can be empty (but should have virtual destructor), then you can store pointer of that type.

```
class Target
{
public:
    virtual ~Target(){}
};

class Player : public Target
{
    ...
};

class NPC : public Target
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: I'm setting this up atm. What does the virtual destructor do out of curiosity?

Comment: @Matthew If you try to delete `Player` or `NPC` having pointer to them of type `Target` the virtual destructor will cause calling of correct destructor (i.e. destructor of class which object is really should be deleted), but in other case you will have memory leak in your program.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. That's the basis for polymorphism, correct?

Comment: Yes @Matthew virtual functions also virtual inheritance are basis of polymorphism in c++.

Comment: Yes, in this case, the destructor would be polymorphic. If you have a pointer of type `Target*` and you `delete` it, which destructors will be called depends on the actual subtype of the referenced object.

Comment: @dosendoc Actually it calls **dynamic-type** of pointer (object) :)

Answer (score 3):

You could make a base class `Targetable`, from which both `Player` and `NPC` inherit, then use a pointer of type `Targetable*`.

Comment: `class Player : public Target`. You'll have to implement methods like `void Target::shot()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base class if they really have some common interface. Maybe something like this:

```
class Target { /* common interface, like a method both Player and NPC use */ };
class Player : public Target { ... };
class NPC    : public Target { ... };
```

If you don't have a common interface you shouldn't use this. You then have to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inheritance by deriving your classes `Player` and `NPC` from a base class, say `GameCharacter` (which on its hand is possibly derived from `GameObject` or what ever). Then you could just declare one target: `GameCharacter* target;`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use inheritance, derive both classes from a single base class as others have suggested.
2. Declare a `union` having pointers of both of these classes.
3. Use `void*`
4. Use C-style or `reinterpret_cast` to convert one class to another class type.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ah !

I'm programming a game too, and I did a bit of conception myself.

Using inheritance is the good way, but the answers with a "targetable" base class are not optimal. Obviously, what "character" and "non player character" have in common (inheritance) is not the "targetable" attribute, it's the whole "character" : (tree is for inheritance)

- character :

  - non-player character
  - player character

If you think about it, the "targetable" property is not restricted to characters. That gives us :

- interactive things : (targetable but also have a size, a weight, etc.)

  - passive or inanimated = object, artifact (you may want to target an object)

    - door (for example bashing a door)
    - statue
    - etc.
  - active or animated = usually living things

    - mobs (can fight but not speak with a player)
    - characters (additional functions like speaking)

      - non-player characters
      - player characters

Of course this is a very rough conception, but you get the point. What I mean is that you'd better do paper-design if you don't want to re-implement it again and again.

Good luck !